# Convert inline javascript to external file

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, carousel, external-js

I am working on a carousel in w3school. They actually have an inline javascript code and I am trying to convert it to an external javascript file. I have this code in my external file

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
}, false);
```

But when I navigate the carousel, it displays error `Uncaught ReferenceError: currentSlide is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick` and does not work/navigate the images in the carousel

This is the HTML code

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img class="carousel-item" src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/1">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img class="carousel-item" src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/2">
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide-nav">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/components.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `currentSlide` is not globally accessible (HTML inline event handlers run in the global scope). You need to define it in the global scope for it to work:

```
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {...}, false);
```